How to obtain updated timezone identifiers on MacOS?
I am trying to get the updated timezone identifier for a cross-platform application. I have the Linux side handled, but am having difficulty finding information around how to get this on MacOS (not my native OS) using Objective-C (not my native language). (The application is written in Go, so the foreign calls need to be to Objective-C rather than Swift).
I have found the documentation for struct TimeZone and autoupdatingCurrent which look to be the things that I want.
It looks to me like I want to get autoupdatingCurrent.identifier, but I am unable to find any clear example of how to do this. As far as I can see from the documentation, I should just be able to reference autoupdatingCurrent.identifier to get the string, but this is not working for me, so I am obviously missing something.
Can someone either point me to good documentation for this, or point to/provide a brief example that I can learn from?

Please show the actual code that "is not working for me". Explain, with reference to that code, what you are hoping to do and what is happening instead.

Your question is tagged Objective-C but you link to Swift-only constructs. For ObjcC check here, the intro spells it pretty much out: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone?language=objc

kortschak, FWIW, when you are looking at the Apple documentation, in the upper right hand corner, it will tell you whether it is Swift documentation or Objective-C documentation (and if it is some type available from both languages, you can toggle back and forth between them).

Gerd and Rob, thank you both. That looks like it will have been the issue. I'll try with that (correct) documentation.

From Objective-C, you want to use the classes that start with NS (e.g., NSCalendar rather than Swift’s Calendar, NSTimeZone rather than Swift’s TimeZone, etc.).
Thus, in Objective-C (for me in Los Angeles, CA):
NSString *name = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar.timeZone.name;
NSLog(@"timezone name %@", name);                                       // America/Los_Angeles

NSString *name2 = [[[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] timeZone] name];
NSLog(@"timezone name %@", name2);                                      // America/Los_Angeles

NSString *abbreviation = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar.timeZone.abbreviation;
NSLog(@"timezone abbreviation %@", abbreviation);                       // PDT (aka, “Pacific Daylight Time”)

NSString *abbreviation2 = [[[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] timeZone] abbreviation];
NSLog(@"timezone abbreviation %@", abbreviation2);                      // PDT

NSString *abbreviation3 = [NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar.timeZone abbreviationForDate:[NSDate now]];
NSLog(@"timezone abbreviation %@", abbreviation3);                      // PDT

NSString *abbreviation4 = [[[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] timeZone] abbreviationForDate:[NSDate now]];
NSLog(@"timezone abbreviation %@", abbreviation4);                      // PDT

I include both the contemporary “dot syntax”, as well as the legacy Objective-C […] syntax. I assume you would use the former, the “dot syntax”, from Go, but I am not familiar with how these “Foundation” types are exposed. But, hopefully, the above helps.

You reference struct TimeZone. That is a Swift struct. I gather you are not interested in Swift interfaces, but if you were, here are demonstrations of the Swift API:
let name = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.timeZone.identifier
print("timezone name", name);                                           // America/Los_Angeles

if let abbreviation = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.timeZone.abbreviation(for: .now) {
    print("timezone abbreviation", abbreviation);                       // PDT
}


FWIW, you reference autoupdatingCurrent.identifier. That is the identifier for the calendar (e.g. gregorian vs chinese), not the timezone. And that is Swift. In Objective-C, it would be:
NSString *calendarIdentifier = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar.calendarIdentifier;
NSLog(@"calendar identifier = %@", calendarIdentifier);                 // gregorian

NSString *calendarIdentifier2 = [[NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] calendarIdentifier];
NSLog(@"calendar identifier = %@", calendarIdentifier2);                // gregorian


Thank you Rob. I'll check this out and when confirmed accept this outstanding answer.

For others with equally limited Objective C background, the required header is <Foundation/Foundation.h>.

I have a follow up. autoupdatingCurrentCalendar does not appear to be doing what I expect; I expect it to provide the current, potentially updated, time zone ID. However, when I run a program that polls this value (for example here https://go.dev/play/p/3mNSP4mrZs9) and then change the time zone via settings, the returned value does not change.

The autoupdatingCurrentCalendar is auto-updating. See this Swift example. The problem here is not with the auto-updating calendar, but I am guessing that it is a result that you are spinning on the main thread, which never gives the calendar to get updated with the new timezone.

Thanks Rob. In the C code I have a second sleep, which should give things enough time to update, and in the actual Go program, we have sleep and numerous syscalls and GC that would also be relinquishing time to the OS, so I would have thought we'd see the expected behaviour, but we don't.

See this for example that works in Go (using dispatch_main). There might be other ways, too: I'm not a Go programer. But the problem is not the calendar, per se, but rather the interaction with Go’s threading model. BTW, re autoUpdatingCurrent, but you don't need that. You aren't referring to the same calendar instance on every call, so it doesn't matter if it is auto-updating or not.

Thanks again. Yes, I was thinking that the problem is essentially two concurrency models that are fighting each other. The real application has the polling happen in a goroutine, so it looks like I need to add C.dispatch_main() somewhere sensible. As a non-mac dev, I find this horrifying, but I guess if it has to happen, it has to happen. Thank you so much for digging into this. I'll also play with the auto-updating part.
